# How to do cross validation of linear model with transformed variable in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm trying to do cross validation of a linear model with transformed independent variable, but most CV functions([`DAAG::cvLm()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DAAG/versions/1.22/topics/CVlm), [`cvTools::repCV()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cvTools/versions/0.3.2/topics/repCV), etc) cannot process because it cannot find `x3` or `x4` in the data. I guess I can generate `x5=log(x3)` and `x6=I(x4 %in% c("A", "B")` and re-estimate. But is there a function that can take care of it automatically?

```
set.seed(666)

DF <- data.table::data.table(x1=rnorm(100), x2=runif(100, 3, 5), x3=rnorm(100, 10, 2),
                         x4=sample(c("A","B","C","D"), 100, replace = T))
DF[,`:=`( y1= 2*x1+3*x2+4*log(x3)+rnorm(100),
          y2= x1+x2+I(!x4 %in% c("C","D"))+rnorm(100))]

lm1 <- lm(y1~x1+x2+log(x3), data=DF)
lm2 <- lm(y2~x1+x2+I(!x4 %in% c("C","D")), data=DF)

cvTools::repCV(lm1)
```

> Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'x3' not found

```
cvTools::cvLm(lm2)
```

> Error in x4 %in% c("C", "D") : object 'x4' not found

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Are `x3` and `x4` not in your data? Can you make a reproducible example by either sharing a little sample data or demonstrating on a built-in data set and showing some of your cross validation code?

Comment: Just added code for replication. Thanks!